# Symbolic integration of a sigmoid function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'd like to obtain a symbolic result for the following integral:

```
Sigmoid[x_] := 1/(1 + Exp[-x])
Integrate[Sigmoid[x]*Log[Sigmoid[x*w]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

The correct answer is `-Pi^2 (w^2 + 1)/(12w)`.

Mathematica *can* do it for explicit small integer values of $w$ (eg, w=1 or w=2).

Comment: **Why can't it do this?** well, Maple can't. Rubi can't. Fricas can't. So it is not only Mathematica which can't.  May be chatGPT can :)

Comment: This function is available under the name [LogisticSigmoid](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogisticSigmoid.html).

Comment: @Nasser Trust me when I say that chatGPT can't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Sigmoid[x_] := 1/(1 + Exp[-x])

seq = Table[
  Integrate[Sigmoid[x]*Log[Sigmoid[x*w]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], 
  {w, 1, 5}]

(* {-(π^2/6), -((5 π^2)/24), -((5 π^2)/18), -((17 π^2)/48), 
  -((13 π^2)/30)} *)
```

Using [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to generalize,

```
int[w_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, w] // Simplify

(* -((π^2 (1 + w^2))/(12 w)) *)
```

Comparing with numeric integration,

```
intN[w_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Sigmoid[x]*Log[Sigmoid[x*w]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Plot[{int[w], intN[w]}, {w, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing me how I could have done this. I guess I did the same thing, manually: doing numerical approximations in C++, plotting those and then guessing what the underlying function is. I did `Sigmoid[x]*Log[Sigmoid[x*w + b]]` that way too in the meantime (note the extra +b).

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't have a full solution, but I just want to log what work I've managed so far.

Intuitively I just randomly tried breaking the integrand down using the (even / odd ) function transform `f(x) -> (f(x)+f(-x))/2 + (f(x)+f(x))/2`.  This makes the numerator much cleaner looking. The even part integrates easily. The odd part really breaks down into this integral:

```
Integrate[Log[1 + E^(-w x)]/(1 + E^x), x]
```

or with a substitution:

```
Log[1 + u^w]/(u (1 + u))
```

This is the simplest version of your problem I could find. My caclulus skills aren't exceptional, but I couldn't get any techniques to handle this that I know (tried differentiating under the integral sign wrt to w, but this doesn't work), so I'd probably bring this to the math stackexchange after searching for a bit.

Comment: My guess is that the integral itself is everything but simple. Mathematica loves to produce lots of PolyLog terms in the result. It's just that the integral from -inf to +inf becomes remarkably simple again.

Comment: This is the context in which I needed this / the work that I did that led to this: https://github.com/CarloWood/machine-learning/blob/8a69df9d49b370f8261e819511ab6c124656c998/src/README.binary_classification#L498
Then on line 521 the result for x*w + b. Turns out that all I did was derive in my own way the binary cross-entropy loss function :)